# Make configurable horizontal scroll Menu using Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Check my [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/7UpEQPYyicl3hpqcPnHH?p=preview), currently everything is hardcoded i.e. number of menuitems are fixed 10, currentMargin. But as per requirement there can be 'n' number of menuitem which will be scrollable horizontally. I tried to make it configurable but not able to as am new to Angular.

So here are the things which I want to achieve:

1. 'MoveLeft' & 'Moveright' button should be visible only if my Menuitem exceeds 3.
2. Making it configurable, there can be 'n' number of menuitem.
3. While reaching to the first 3 'MoveLeft' button will be disabled.
4. While reaching to the last 3 'MoveRight' button will be disabled.
5. making the right and left moving of menuitems little smoother.

Please see above given plnkr link to see it in action.
Here is my code,
**HTML Code**

```
 <div ng-controller="scrollController">
<input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveLeft()}" ng-disabled="leftdisabled" class="left" type="button" value="Move Left" />
<div class="menucontainer left">
  <ul ng-style="myStyle">
    <li> <a href="#">111</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">222</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">333</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">444</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">555</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">666</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">777</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">888</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">999</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">000</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveRight()}" ng-disabled="rightdisabled" class="left" type="button" value="Move Right" />
</div>
```

**Angular JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('scrollController', function($scope) {
 $scope.myStyle = {
   'margin-left': '0px'
 };

$scope.moveRight = function() {
var marginLeft = +$scope.myStyle['margin-left'].replace('px', '') + -100;

if (marginLeft === 0) {
  $scope.leftdisabled = true;
}
else{
  $scope.leftdisabled = false;
}

 if (marginLeft === -700) {
  $scope.rightdisabled = true;
}
else{
  $scope.rightdisabled = false;
}

$scope['margin-left'] = marginLeft + 'px';
document.getElementById('infoMargin').innerHTML=marginLeft;
return $scope['margin-left'];

}

$scope.moveLeft = function() {
var marginLeft = +$scope.myStyle['margin-left'].replace('px', '') + 100;

if (marginLeft === 0) {
  $scope.leftdisabled = true;
}
else{
  $scope.leftdisabled = false;
}

if (marginLeft === -700) {
  $scope.rightdisabled = true;
}
else{
  $scope.rightdisabled = false;
}

$scope['margin-left'] = marginLeft + 'px';
document.getElementById('infoMargin').innerHTML=marginLeft;
return $scope['margin-left'];
}

})
```

Comment: till now achieved http://plnkr.co/edit/vSrQgWA9qJv5J1XpTGuo?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have done some changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hxut4UgN0d3pMeBbSbzl?p=preview

update(with <= 3 menus button will hide): http://plnkr.co/edit/LdVLubl1DKtij4KMWoHd?p=preview

Code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="scrollController" >
    <input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveLeft()}" ng-disabled="leftdisabled" class="left" type="button" value="Move Left" />
    <div class="menucontainer left">
      <ul ng-style="myStyle">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items"> <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>

        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveRight()}" ng-disabled="rightdisabled" class="left" type="button" value="Move Right" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p style="float:left;">Current Margin :</p>
    <p style="float:left;" id="infoMargin"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>If current Margin reaches to -700 it I am disabling 'MoveRight"' and if it reaches to Zero i am disabling 'MoveLeft' button.</p>
    <p><b>Need help to make it configurable as currently every thing is hardcoded, there can be 'n' number of menuitem.</b></p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js

// Code goes here

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('scrollController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myStyle = {
    'float':'left',
    'margin-left': '0px',
    'display':'block'
  };
  var items = [];
  $scope.items = [{name:"111",age:25},{name:"222",age:25},{name:"333",age:25},{name:"444",age:25},{name:"555",age:25},{name:"666",age:25}];

  $scope.moveRight = function() {
    var marginLeft = +$scope.myStyle['margin-left'].replace('px', '') + -100;

    if (marginLeft === 0) {
      $scope.leftdisabled = true;
    }
    else{
      $scope.leftdisabled = false;
    }

     if (marginLeft === -(($scope.items.length-3)*100)) {
      $scope.rightdisabled = true;
    }
    else{
      $scope.rightdisabled = false;
    }

    $scope['margin-left'] = marginLeft + 'px';
    document.getElementById('infoMargin').innerHTML=marginLeft;
    return $scope['margin-left'];

  }

  $scope.moveLeft = function() {
    var marginLeft = +$scope.myStyle['margin-left'].replace('px', '') + 100;

    if (marginLeft === 0) {
      $scope.leftdisabled = true;
    }
    else{
      $scope.leftdisabled = false;
    }

    if (marginLeft === -700) {
      $scope.rightdisabled = true;
    }
    else{
      $scope.rightdisabled = false;
    }

    $scope['margin-left'] = marginLeft + 'px';
    document.getElementById('infoMargin').innerHTML=marginLeft;
    return $scope['margin-left'];
  }

})
```

Comment: thanks, can you please update the plunker for Initial disabling and making button visible only when there are more then 3 item. I tried the approach suggested by @david in your updated plunk but not able to.

Comment: ohh.. I was away for a while. 
I made it like if end point for either side is reached buttons will get disabled.
So did you finally found your solution?

Comment: any idea how can we can we make button visible only when there are more then 3 items

Comment: Here see the updated one. Revert if you find any issue with this one.
http://plnkr.co/edit/LdVLubl1DKtij4KMWoHd?p=preview

Comment: thanks, i updated new link in answer, so it might be helpful for others as well.

Comment: Yeah saw that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As AngularHarsh has shown, Angular is best used when dealing with JSON data.

Generally, when using Angular to manipulate lists of items, you would use it for JSON data. This makes it much easier to use Angular to hide, display, filter and animate data. But to address the goals you want to achieve:

1. To only display the moveLeft and moveRight buttons when there are greater than 3 items in the list, first Angular needs to know how many items are in the list. We can do this by setting it as a scope variable (I would just put `$scope.menuItems = 10;` at the top of the controller, or, `$scope.menuItems = $("myList li").length();` if you don't want a hardcoded number. Usually this would just be set to the length of the JSON data received).

   Now that Angular knows how many items are in the list, through the $scope.menuItems variable, we need to tell the HTML to only show those buttons when there are more than 3 items. We can do this by using Angular's [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) attribute. We use it like this:

   ```
   <input ng-show="menuItems > 3" />
   ```

   Note we don't need to write $scope.menuItems when using scope variables in the HTML.
2. Making the number of items configurable, you'll get this by default when using the code written above. Again, using JSON makes this easier, but if you are just reading the elements from the html, find the number of list items written in the HTML, tell angular through a scope variable, and use that scope variable in the HTML where you need it.
3. Disabling MoveLeft button when you are all the way to the left. Okay you kind of already have this implemented, but the way you are doing it means that Angular will only know you are all the way to the left *after* MoveLeft has been pressed (Inside your moveLeft and moveRight functions you perform the check). What you should do is make sure that code is run when the page is loaded. You can do this by having that check code sitting inside your controller.
4. Disabling MoveRight button, see above.
5. Making the movement smoother. I'm guessing you mean animations? Well the way you have it set up at the moment is a bit different to how I would normally do it. Your list of items is basically always on the page, but which part is displayed get shown depending on it's margin position. I would generally hide (using display: none; or using angular's ng-show/ng-hide) the list items I don't want to be seen. Angular has some animation functionality that works based on when elements enter or exit the view, which you can read about here: http://www.nganimate.org/

I made an update to your PLUNKR to show what I mean by checking for list position on page load (numbers 3 and 4 above), and to show how ng-show is used (number 1 above). http://plnkr.co/edit/MJwDhfrO9benr9PU2tHb?p=preview

Comment: $scope.menuItems = $("myList li").length(); here mylist li are class name right? i am not able to count number of items configurably?

Comment: What do you mean configurably? If you end up using JSON data to populate the list, you can set $scope.menuItems to the number of items in the JSON object. If you don't end up using JSON, you can manually count the number of elements on the page using jQuery.